# TBitBtn with proper theming?

Tags: delphi, button, themes, glyph, uxtheme

If you take a look at a standard TButton on Windows 7 and above, hovering the mouse over the button will produce a subtle fade in effect, while taking the cursor away will make the hot face of the button fade out quickly.

If you check the same with a TBitBtn you'll see that there's no fade effect; it changes to the hot state without any transition then changes back without any transition too.

Is there any component similar to TBitBtn that can display a picture and that is properly themed at the same time?

Comment: A TButton, like in the deleted answer.

Comment: @Sertac: But what about the rendering bug?

Comment: @Andreas - I don't know that, what bug?

Comment: @Sertac: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551323/delphi-2010-image-on-tbutton-fading-blinking

Comment: @Andreas - I can't seem to duplicate that, with double buffering off. When it's on, there's no breathing effect at all. In neither case the image is fading here.

Comment: @Sertac: On my system, there is a lot of fading, but [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19238341/282848) works. Example: http://privat.rejbrand.se/buttoniconflashing.mp4

Comment: If you want native themeing you use the native controls. And don't use double buffering.

Comment: No, there can't be such a component because an imagelist can serve to more than one button/control. Please don't make your questions moving targets.

Comment: @Sertac What if we derived a class out of TButton that would include an ImageList as a private property? Would that be very resource consuming? Is there a limit to the number of ImageLists you can create? I created a separate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929844/is-there-a-component-that-behaves-like-a-tbitbtn-that-is-properly-themed

Comment: @Steve - My opinion is, it would be quite reasonable, resourcewise. I didn't look at the question yet though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `TButton` which is a native Windows BUTTON control, and it does support icons via an image list. But beware of [the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551323/delphi-2010-image-on-tbutton-fading-blinking)!

Comment: @Steve I rolled back your edit. You cannot wait 10 hours until your question is commented on, and answered, and then change the question.

Comment: @David, I'm sorry, I'll post it as a separate question.